# how to check all the records in column having bigint type or not in scala, while writing unit test cases?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, scalatest

```
val types = for(i <- result) yield i.column_name.isInstanceOf[Option[BigInt]]
assert(result.forall(_.column_name.isInstanceOf[Option[BigInt]]
```

does it efficient enough?

can anyone share better version of this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [the ScalaTest matchers](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithIterators) you can try this way:

```
  val columnNames = result.map(_.column_name)
  all (columnNames) should be a [Option[BigInt]]
```